# linux sed and lm sensors

Tags: sed

I am using the following

```
while true; do sensors | grep 'Core 1'| sed -r 's/^.*: +(.*) +[(].*$/\1/' >> lmdata.txt; sleep 300;  done
```

to format

```
Core 1:       +68.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

to

```
+68.0'C
```

how can i alter the sed command to only get the temp ie

```
68
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sensors|sed -nE '/Core 1:/s/[^+]*\+([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/p'
```

In plain language, that could read:

Using `sed` in non-echoing mode with extended regexes:

- on line matching *Core 1:*
- search for...
- anything other than a +
- then a +
- then save any more than 1 digit
- then match to the end of the line
- replace with...
- the first saved pattern
- and print the result

Comment: Well explained. Probably a good idea for teaching since it's unlikely the edges was developed by the OP. Kudos.

Comment: Thanks! @cunninghamp3 I like to live by the phrase "give a man a match and he'll be warm for a day; douse him in kerosene first and he'll be warm for the rest of his life". No better example than regexes!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update the sed portion of your command to this without restructuring anything else:

```
sed -r 's/^.*: +([[:digit:]]+).* +[(].*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grep with perl-regexp:

```
$ sensors|grep -oP "Core 1:\s*\+\K[0-9]+"
70
```

Comment: Super thanks very much i have spent hours trying to figure it out thanks again